# How to display image based on selected option

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get an image to display based on user choice.

This is the `contentType` table

```
id | Type | Image |
```

The options are retrieved from a while statement as follow :

```
   <select style="cursor:pointer;" id="contentMarketingTypeSelector" name="contentMarketingType" class="form-control contentMarketingType">
<option>Please select content type</option>';
        while($ctype = $resultstmt_uppt->fetch_assoc()){
        $socialmediaform .= '<option id="'.$ctype['Type'].'">'.$ctype['Type'].'</option>';
          }
</select>
```

I'd like to display the image outside the while as follow :

```
<div class='contentImageType'></div>
```

I started this with jQuery

```
 $(function() {
                $('#contentMarketingTypeSelector').change(function(){


                });
            });
```

I'm a bit lost from here...Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast and really easy jQuery solution. Set the value to `<option>` and id to `<select>`.

Html

```
 <div class='contentImageType'>
<img style="max-width:100% !important;" class="responsive" src="" name="image-swap">
</div>
```

Php

```
  <select style="cursor:pointer;" id="contentMarketingTypeSelector" name="contentMarketingType" class="form-control contentMarketingType">
<option>Please select content type</option>';
        while($ctype = $resultstmt_uppt->fetch_assoc()){
        $socialmediaform .= '<option value="'.$ctype['Image'].'">'.$ctype['Type'].'</option>';
          }
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
                $('#contentMarketingTypeSelector').change(function(){

                  $("img[name=image-swap]").attr("src",$(this).val());

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get help from [Select2](https://select2.org) plugins

https://select2.org/dropdown